# My Android tablet seems to be "read-only"

Tags: storage

I got an iView 7" Android tablet about a week ago, and it's been doing fine until today. [This is the product on NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16858683003)

In short; it seems my internal storage just won't accept any changes of any kind, which is causing all manner of odd errors.

I have gone to the extent of trying a Factory Reset; powering off, holding Vol-Up, Home and Power; waiting for the prompts, and choosing the Factory Reset option. But it did not work - after rebooting, everything is just like it was before; My ADW Desktop is still there; all my programs and data, everything.

---

Of course, it's not usable as is, though; Programs don't work as intended. Some (Like Facebook and Calendar Storage) Force Quit as soon as I unlock the home screen. Others will Force Quit during operation - usually, one can tell, when it's needing to save some data. Yet others appear to operate, but don't save their data; the program apparently just 'swallows' the error.

Some system functions don't even work; for instance, I can't connect to WIFI; when I turn it on, the WIFI item in the settings area just shows "Error".

I can't even uninstall programs. Well, I can; But as soon as I reboot, they are back.

Via the file manager, I can not modify any of the files on the user area of the internal SD Card.

The tablet is rooted (it comes rooted; I did not do this myself), and using ES File Explorer I can go to /system/app/ and I can, for example, rename APK's and it appears to take effect as you would expect, but then as soon as I reboot, the program is back in the state it was in before.

All I have done with root access on this device is installed Superuser and ES, then mounted the system so I could rename the `Phone.apk` and `Telephony.apk` files so they would not run, since this is a tablet with WIFI only. I did that as soon as I got the table last week, and it hasn't given me any other troubles. Now, those files can't be renamed *back* to their original permanently.

---

So, I'm wondering if perhaps my internal memory card is fried or something? It seems odd that the behavior would be so predictable with a hardware error like that, but who knows?

Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved the issue, though I have no idea why or how it occurred.

What I did was flash the ROM, including reformatting the internal storage. In the process, I've updated the tablet to ICS.

I won't accept this answer right away because I'm not sure if someone might have experienced this recently and knows a bit more about it than I do.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue with my VOX V81 tablet. I formatted its internal storage and did a factory reset. But when I rebooted it, it came to its previous state.

I suppose that it is due to the Avast Mobile security I installed on this tablet; after installing Avast, this problem started. So I suggest you to uninstall any antivirus or mobile security application.

Comment: In my case, factory reset also did not work. I needed to actually flash the ROM and completely reformat the thing. I still have no clue why it happened in my case; I didn't have any antivirus/security apps installed at all. But this might help someone else with the same problem, so +1